# How to delete a file whose name is given by a character array?

Tags: matlab

I want to delete a file with variables in the file name. But MATLAB doesn't seem to recognize the file name when using `delete`. Can anyone help me?

```
ratio=1;
a=2;
nameoffile3=['r' num2str(ratio) '_a' num2str(a) '.txt'];
delete nameoffile3
```

Comment: hi, thank you for your reply. It's in the current directory. If I type 'delete r1_a2.txt' ,  it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete a file whose name is given by a character array, use `delete` with parenthesis `()` i.e.

```
delete(nameoffile3)
```